# Can sqlite trigger call java method in android?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Can sqlite  trigger   call java method  in  android?

I  create  a trigger  for  tableA, when insert tableA, trigger will  insert new data in  tableB.

I have to  make reaction once  tableB have  new  datas.  I think polling is the  worst choice. So  I  thinking  about  how  can  I  call java method in trigger.

Waiting  online , thanks~

Comment: No, unfortunately. There's no such thing as SQLite server, so nobody can call us back. You can review Room's InvalidationTracker which shows how to make polling efficiently: it checks for triggers' side-effects after each transaction.